# How to start a second tkinter program from another and then close first?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a tkinter gui that I would like to run. This app will do some house cleaning of sorts. It would check files, check for updates, give the user some information etc. Then I would like it to start another tkinter application and then close it self.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
    

def StartProgram():
    os.startfile("C:/WINDOWS/system32/notepad.exe")
    

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

button = tk.Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red",  command= lambda: quit())
button.pack( side=tk.LEFT)
button2 = tk.Button(frame,text="Start my exe", command=lambda: StartProgram())
button2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
root.maxsize(200,200)
root.minsize(200,200)   
root.mainloop()
```

The problem I have so far is when I attempt to close the original app it closes the one it started as well.
**EDIT**: I also tried root.destroy(), root.quit()

Any suggestion how I might correct this?

Comment: Why aren't you using `import path.to.my.app`?

Comment: Also you have to post more code. My guess is that you can just use `<tkinter.Tk>.destroy()` to destroy the own window and then you can import your other file

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre].

Comment: I added the simple program I'm using to test.  The reason I don't want to use import is that I may want to update my apps EXE with a new version or put back an older version.  This way once I set it up how I want then I would start the new app.  With this test I'm just using notepad.  I click one button it starts then I want to hit quite to close the app leaving notepad running.

Comment: `lambda: <function name>()` is the same as just having `<function name>`. Also try adding `root.destroy()` to start of your `StartProgram` function

Comment: If I don't use lambda: it will run those before even loading the frame.  I only want them to run when pressing the buttons.  Tried the root.destroy() but it still closes the notepad that was open along with the app.  I only want the original app to close not the notepad.

Comment: You can remove the lambda by changing `button = tk.Button(...,  command= lambda: quit())` to `button = tk.Button(...,  command=quit)`. Note `quit` isn't going to run immediately because I removed the "`()`". It will run when you press the button.

Comment: Try changing the `os.startfile` to something like `os.system`. Even when you use `root.destroy()` it shouldn't close the notepad.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the lambda issue that actually very useful information.  So thank you.   I will try changing to .system  when i get a chance and report back.

Comment: OK, switching os.startfile to os.system appears to have done the trick here.  Thank you all for your support with this issue and moving me a little further down the programming path.